# How to connect tkcon to a tcl/tk GUI over ssh

Tags: ssh, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a fullscreen Tk GUI application running in a virtual machine.

I know I can `"Attach to ... Interpreter"` from Tkcon to the GUI within the virtual machine.

Unfortunately, since the application always runs full screen, the tkcon dialog is hidden behind it.

I understand, I can use `ALT - TAB` to switch between tkcon and the fullscreen GUI. It works as long as you are ok with regularly switching back and forth.

### Question:

Only I was wondering if it is possible to run tkcon in a 2nd monitor (on a windows or linux host, for example) and connect over ssh to the GUI running in the virtual machine. I can see that tkcon has an `"Attach to ... socket"` option.

### What I have tried:

I thought I could,

1. run Putty.
2. Connect to the virtual machine over ssh with X-forwarding enabled.
3. Launch tkcon in the VM from the Putty terminal.
4. *And connect to the GUI running in the virtual machine.* - except that this last step does not work. I can not see the list of 'discovered' interpreters in tkcon under `Attach to ... Interpreters`.

Which makes me wonder as well, how the tkcon 'discovers' the Interpreters in the virtual machine.

Thank you for your time&help.

Comment: Just a little followup (I wasn't sure if I should edit my post or add a comment here), in case one day I come back stumbling to this question again. I tried something today, which I dunno why, I hadn't thought of earlier. Instead of running the full screen GUI application inside the VM, I launched it from the terminal of the host, from where I was logged into the VM over ssh. I am surprised the app ran without errors. The full-screen GUI-app interpreter now is visible to both the VM's tkcon launched over ssh, as well as, the tkcon on the host. I can connect from either of them to the GUI.

Comment: I can even relegate the VM to a headless mode and work completely on the host. `:)` But anyways, it was nice to learn about tkconclient from Donal Fellow's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkcon has two real options for attaching to another interpreter:

1. Tk's built-in [`send` command](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/send.htm), which works via Xserver properties and is a bit finicky for getting things enabled. This can communicate directly with any other Tk on the same Xserver. Using SSH to secure things is going to be all about doing the usual remote X11 access tunnels.
2. The [`tkconclient`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tkcon+Remote+Access+over+TCP+Sockets) package (see that wiki page for the source code) that you run *in the interpreter you wish to control*. Then you attach to it with tkcon (though you'll need to know what port to connect to). You'll need to set up an ordinary SSH tunnel for that; by default it only allows local connections (and that's a good thing).

Note that the client code must be running an event loop. That's no problem for any GUI application, anything that's answering other server sockets, or in fact usually anything that's doing plenty of thread management. Which covers most interesting applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Donal Fellows. I try your suggestions and then get back here. Thanks again. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. Holidays `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` ! I just tested and went with your second solution. I am partially successfully at least. Indeed the tkcon on the host can connect to the interpreter on the host. I just have to figure out where best to put this tkconclient script in the VM.

Comment: ... _can connect to the interpreter on the host._ --> I mean't **guest**. Typo.